# How to understand the nature of an imported .pkl file

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I imported the file edges.pkl for my code. I wish to understand the type/nature of this file which I am storing in `edges` . For this I've tried to print the following code. Can someone help me in understanding the type of this file? So that I can further process it! I want to slice the edges file into a smaller file (with less entries) so that I can run it with less computational resources!

**Code:**

```
with open('data/'+args.dataset+'/edges.pkl','rb') as f:
    edges = pickle.load(f)

    
print('.......')

isinstance(edges, list)
print('edges',len(edges))
print('edges_shape',np.shape(edges))
print('1:5',edges[1::5])
print('1:2',edges[1::2])
print('edges_0',(edges[0,:]))
print('edges_1',len(edges[1]))

print('.......')
```

Error:

> .......
>
> edges 4
>
> edges_shape (4,)
>
> 1:5 [<18405x18405 sparse matrix of
> type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'  with 19645 stored elements in Compressed
> Sparse Column format>]
>
> 1:2 [<18405x18405 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'   with
> 19645 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>,
> <18405x18405 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'    with 14328
> stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>]
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/anshumansinha/Desktop/GTN_gatech/main.py", line 66, in
>
> print('edges_0',(edges[0,:])) TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

..
**Additional code:**

```
num_nodes = edges[0].shape[0]
    print('num_nodes', num_nodes)
for i,edge in enumerate(edges): # i goesthrough numbers [0,1,2,3...] and edge through edges.
        
        print('i',i)
        print('edge.shape', edge.shape)
        print('edge',edge)
        
        if i ==0:
             A = tf.expand_dims(tf.convert_to_tensor(edge.todense(), dtype= tf.float32), -1)
        else:
             A = tf.concat((A,tf.expand_dims(tf.convert_to_tensor(edge.todense(), dtype= tf.float32), -1)), -1) 
    
    A = tf.concat((A, tf.expand_dims(tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.eye(num_nodes), dtype= tf.float32), -1) ), -1)
    
   
    print('shape',A.shape)
```

**Output:**
...

```
num_nodes 18405
i 0
edge.shape =  (18405, 18405)
edge   (4057, 438)  1
  (4058, 1945)  1
  (4059, 866)   1
  (4059, 1945)  1
  (4060, 472)   1
  (4060, 1299)  1
  (4060, 2250)  1
  (4061, 1415)  1
  (4062, 2437)  1
  (4063, 289)   1
  (4064, 3381)  1
  (4064, 3852)  1
  (4065, 1605)  1
  (4066, 1317)  1
  (4066, 3355)  1
  (4067, 2898)  1
  (4068, 3951)  1
  (4069, 1746)  1
  (4070, 3041)  1
  (4071, 468)   1
  (4072, 1809)  1
  (4073, 1352)  1
  (4074, 1352)  1
  (4075, 747)   1
  (4076, 1890)  1
  : :
  (18367, 4001) 1
  (18368, 3169) 1
  (18369, 206)  1
  (18370, 107)  1
  (18370, 2020) 1
  (18371, 1532) 1
  (18372, 1671) 1
  (18373, 1599) 1
  (18374, 582)  1
  (18374, 1963) 1
  (18375, 920)  1
  (18376, 1590) 1
  (18376, 3044) 1
  (18377, 248)  1
  (18378, 596)  1
  (18379, 2690) 1
  (18380, 1434) 1
  (18381, 470)  1
  (18381, 2766) 1
  (18382, 1547) 1
  (18383, 3350) 1
  (18384, 334)  1
  (18384, 470)  1
  (18384, 1590) 1
  (18384, 3044) 1
2022-07-10 16:58:36.500345: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
i 1
edge.shape =  (18405, 18405)
edge   (438, 4057)  1
  (1945, 4058)  1
  (866, 4059)   1
  (1945, 4059)  1
  (472, 4060)   1
  (1299, 4060)  1
  (2250, 4060)  1
  (1415, 4061)  1
  (2437, 4062)  1
  (289, 4063)   1
  (3381, 4064)  1
  (3852, 4064)  1
  (1605, 4065)  1
  (1317, 4066)  1
  (3355, 4066)  1
  (2898, 4067)  1
  (3951, 4068)  1
  (1746, 4069)  1
  (3041, 4070)  1
  (468, 4071)   1
  (1809, 4072)  1
  (1352, 4073)  1
  (1352, 4074)  1
  (747, 4075)   1
  (1890, 4076)  1
  : :
  (4001, 18367) 1
  (3169, 18368) 1
  (206, 18369)  1
  (107, 18370)  1
  (2020, 18370) 1
  (1532, 18371) 1
  (1671, 18372) 1
  (1599, 18373) 1
  (582, 18374)  1
  (1963, 18374) 1
  (920, 18375)  1
  (1590, 18376) 1
  (3044, 18376) 1
  (248, 18377)  1
  (596, 18378)  1
  (2690, 18379) 1
  (1434, 18380) 1
  (470, 18381)  1
  (2766, 18381) 1
  (1547, 18382) 1
  (3350, 18383) 1
  (334, 18384)  1
  (470, 18384)  1
  (1590, 18384) 1
  (3044, 18384) 1
i 2
edge.shape =  (18405, 18405)
edge   (4057, 18385)    1
  (4058, 18385) 1
  (4059, 18385) 1
  (4060, 18385) 1
  (4061, 18385) 1
  (4062, 18385) 1
  (4063, 18385) 1
  (4064, 18385) 1
  (4065, 18385) 1
  (4066, 18385) 1
  (4067, 18385) 1
  (4068, 18385) 1
  (4069, 18385) 1
  (4070, 18385) 1
  (4071, 18385) 1
  (4072, 18385) 1
  (4073, 18385) 1
  (4074, 18385) 1
  (4075, 18385) 1
  (4076, 18385) 1
  (4077, 18385) 1
  (4078, 18385) 1
  (4079, 18385) 1
  (4080, 18385) 1
  (4081, 18385) 1
  : :
  (18360, 18403)    1
  (18361, 18403)    1
  (18362, 18403)    1
  (18363, 18403)    1
  (18364, 18403)    1
  (18365, 18403)    1
  (18366, 18403)    1
  (18367, 18403)    1
  (18368, 18403)    1
  (18369, 18403)    1
  (18370, 18403)    1
  (18371, 18403)    1
  (18372, 18403)    1
  (18373, 18403)    1
  (18374, 18404)    1
  (18375, 18404)    1
  (18376, 18404)    1
  (18377, 18404)    1
  (18378, 18404)    1
  (18379, 18404)    1
  (18380, 18404)    1
  (18381, 18404)    1
  (18382, 18404)    1
  (18383, 18404)    1
  (18384, 18404)    1
i 3
edge.shape =  (18405, 18405)
edge   (18385, 4057)    1
  (18385, 4058) 1
  (18385, 4059) 1
  (18385, 4060) 1
  (18385, 4061) 1
  (18385, 4062) 1
  (18385, 4063) 1
  (18385, 4064) 1
  (18385, 4065) 1
  (18385, 4066) 1
  (18385, 4067) 1
  (18385, 4068) 1
  (18385, 4069) 1
  (18385, 4070) 1
  (18385, 4071) 1
  (18385, 4072) 1
  (18385, 4073) 1
  (18385, 4074) 1
  (18385, 4075) 1
  (18385, 4076) 1
  (18385, 4077) 1
  (18385, 4078) 1
  (18385, 4079) 1
  (18385, 4080) 1
  (18385, 4081) 1
  : :
  (18403, 18360)    1
  (18403, 18361)    1
  (18403, 18362)    1
  (18403, 18363)    1
  (18403, 18364)    1
  (18403, 18365)    1
  (18403, 18366)    1
  (18403, 18367)    1
  (18403, 18368)    1
  (18403, 18369)    1
  (18403, 18370)    1
  (18403, 18371)    1
  (18403, 18372)    1
  (18403, 18373)    1
  (18404, 18374)    1
  (18404, 18375)    1
  (18404, 18376)    1
  (18404, 18377)    1
  (18404, 18378)    1
  (18404, 18379)    1
  (18404, 18380)    1
  (18404, 18381)    1
  (18404, 18382)    1
  (18404, 18383)    1
  (18404, 18384)    1
shape (18405, 18405, 5)
```

Comment: Looks like `edges` is a `list` with 4 elements.  At least 2 of them, maybe all, are `scipy.sparse` matrices (csc format).  The error is because you try to index the list as though it was a 2d array.

Comment: @hpaulj What about `<18405x18405 sparse matrix of type... >` this statement? Do you know how may I convert the data into an excel file? Or else, slice some small part of this data for further computation instead of working with this large data file!